# What is a good way to maintain links for a navigation view-partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller for my admin panel (`DashboardController`). Dashboard's layout has a view partial containing the unordered list (and sub lists) for the navigation.

Even in a view partial, it feels dirty to hard-code the links, and I would like to setup a loop inside the navigation partial, where I can pass an array that would look something like:

```
[
    {
        "text": "Home",
        "url": "/dashboard",
        "sublinks": []
    },
    {
        "text": "Products",
        "url": "",
        "sublinks": [
            {
                "text": "New Product",
                "url": "/dashboard/products/new",
                "sublinks": []
            },
            {
                "text": "Manage Products",
                "url": "/dashboard/products",
                "sublinks": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "text": "Users",
        "url": "",
        "sublinks": [
            {
                "text": "New User",
                "url": "/dashboard/users/new",
                "sublinks": []
            },
            {
                "text": "Manage Users",
                "url": "/dashboard/users",
                "sublinks": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Where should I stick it, and how do I pass it to the partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of hard coding urls you can use rails path helpers.
  So instead of `/dashboard/products` you should use something like `dashboard_products_path`.
- If your project/admin panel is small, I don't see a problem to write partial w/o config file.
- If you still want to use something with config - the easiest way is to generate array in a helper. Something like:

> ```
> module DashboardsHelper
>   def navigation_data
>     [
>       {
>         text: 'Home',
>         path:  dashboard_path,
>       },
>       ...
>     ]
>   end
> end
> ```

And then you can loop over this array in a partial, and use recursion if `sublinks` exists. If you want to make it more nicer, you can create ruby config file and put configuration to the block. Then yield this block in context of helper and do the same as with previous approach.

- You can take a look at some gems, which can do the job. For example Simple Navigation: https://github.com/codeplant/simple-navigation
- Your navigation file looks very usual, perhaps you can consider to use some ready admin systems, for example like active_admin (http://activeadmin.info/).